# How to set plugin inside directive in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directive that is going to check if my mobile is in landscape or portrait orientation. I want to use plugin matchmedia. How can i set it inside directive?

This is my code:

```
.directive('resizeMobile', function ($window) {
        return {
            controller:'MainController',
            link:function($scope, element, attrs,ctrl) {
                console.log(ctrl.landscape);
                var w = angular.element($window);
                $scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
                    return {
                        'h': w.height(),
                        'w': w.width()
                    };
                };
                $scope.$watch($scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    $scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
                    $scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
                }, true);

                w.bind('resize', function () {
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }

        }
    });

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$window','matchmedia','$http',
    function($scope, $window, matchmedia,$http) {
         this.landscape = matchmedia.isLandscape();
}]);
```

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

All the deal is to add plugin as parameter in a directive's callback function. For example in my case is 
`enter code here`.directive('resizeMobile', function ($window,matchmedia) {
After that to add the needed parameter to $watch

```
myApp
    .directive('resize', function ($window,$http,matchmedia) {

        return function ($scope, element) {

            console.log(element);
            var w = angular.element($window);
            //var a=matchmedia.isPhone();
            //alert(a);
            $scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
                return {
                    'h': w.height(),
                    'w': w.width(),
                    'o': matchmedia.isLandscape()
                };
            };
            $scope.$watch($scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                $scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
                $scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
                $scope.orientation = newValue.o;
            }, true);

            w.bind('resize', function () {
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    })
```